# Unable to ssh into Beaglebone Black from Arch Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, beagleboneblack, archlinux

I have a Beaglebone Black (running on Debian) which I'm connecting to my laptop (running on Arch Linux) through usb. The laptop is able to read Beaglebone as a storage device. However, I am unable to connect to Beaglebone through the browser/ssh by accessing  the following ip -  192.168.7.2.
`ifconfig -a` gives the following output-

```
enp0s20u2: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 54:4a:16:c1:f1:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.3.204  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
    inet6 fe80::2ad2:44ff:fe8e:bd61  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 28:d2:44:8e:bd:61  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 40024  bytes 35440467 (33.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 30  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 17546  bytes 2112866 (2.0 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 2137  bytes 479657 (468.4 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2137  bytes 479657 (468.4 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.10.5.86  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.10.7.255
    ether b8:ee:65:ac:7c:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 19264  bytes 18721516 (17.8 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 17238  bytes 2273813 (2.1 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`enp0s20u2` is the interface of Beaglebone and has no ip allotted to it (as per the documentation, its ip should be 192.168.7.2) and thus I am unable to ssh or browse into it.

Comment: I gave a static ip to its interface  - enp0s20u2  - if this is what you mean. I still wasn't able to ssh or browse into it.

Comment: I ran the following command - `sudo ip link set up enp0s20u2`. Still no moving forward.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm afraid I don't know enough about this area to help, hopefully someone else will provide some helpful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally succeeded by running the following command on the laptop:

```
sudo dhclient <interface>
```

Now, I'm able to ssh/browse Beaglebone Black.

Comment: This works. I even if you don't know the interface just execute ```sudo dhclient```